# Getting this error. Missing { inserted

Tags: math-mode, equations, math-operators

```
\begin{equation}
    \max_{\substack{k , {k^'}}}|{G_k-G_{k^'}}| \leq T_1\\
\end{equation}
```

I am not getting what are the errors. Please help me.

Comment: `\max_{k,k'}|G_k-G_{k'}| \leq T_1` should work. Notice that `^'` is *always* wrong. Remove ``\\``.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 5):

The error you get is

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.7     \max_{\substack{k , {k^'}}
                                  }|{G_k-G_{k^'}}| \leq T_1\\
```

which is indeed puzzling.

The problem starts from `^'`, which is always wrong: `'` is by itself equivalent to `^{\prime}`, so you're trying to make a second level superscript.

Also `\\` at the end is wrong.

Secondary, but still important, is that `\substack` is not needed, as you've nothing to stack; some of the braces you use are redundant and should better be removed. Instead of the “do-it-all” `|` it's better to state the precise usage with `\lvert` and `\rvert`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\max_{k , k'} \lvert G_k-G_{k'}\rvert \leq T_1  
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]